# Order by per group (Query Builder)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have an user and a score table. Each user has multiple scores, for example:

- User1 has 3 scores: 45, 66, 98
- User2 has 2 scores: 75, 45
- User3 has 3 scores: 94, 66, 12

Only the highest score for each user is relevant. What I want to achieve is to get the 10 users that have the highest score. This works with the following laravel query:

```
    $results = Score::orderBy('score', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get()
```

The problem with this query is that it returns the top users, but not their highest score. It returns the first score in the group. So when I query over the given example, this will return:

- 1: User1, 45
- 2: User3, 94
- 3: User2, 75

How can I make sure that it returns the top users with their highest score? I tried to ->distinct('score') but that didn't work.

Comment: You tried to "group-first-then-order" ?

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: is this a typo ? ``->limit(10);->get()`` you use ``;`` after ``limit()``

Comment: Yes edited it, wrong copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$results = Score::select("*", DB::raw("MAX(score) as max")
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderBy('max', 'desc')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: This will return the total sum of all the scores for each user, but only the highest score for each user is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ***(Query Builder)***

Syntax:

```
DB::table('name')->orderBy('column')->groupBy('column')->get();
```

Modify your query:

```
$results = DB::table('score')
    ->orderBy('score', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

-- i don't know well querybuilder but this query solve the problem

```
select top 10 * 
from 
(select userID, max(score) score from yourTable group by userID) K
order by score desc
```

Comment: The question is about how to do it with the querybuilder.

Comment: thanks rocky, i don't know QueryBuilder but i edit my answer, i hope don't screw up

Comment: Then you should not answer this question, when you do not exactly know how to use the querybuilder (: